# Рисунок исчезает при обновлении окна C# Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

У меня возникла проблема с отрисовкой. В переопределенном методе `OnPaint`, использую цикл для рисования нескольких прямоугольников. Они рисуются, но после обновления окна все прямоугольники пропадают.

```
Rectangle rectangle;
        foreach (ColumnData c in columns)
        {
            rectangle = new Rectangle(moveX + 30, (Height - c.getSizeColumn), (Width / columns.Count) - 30, Height);

            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Tomato), rectangle);
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c.getColorColumn), rectangle);

            moveX += (Width / columns.Count) - 30;

        }
```

Comment: Покажите больше кода. Если вы рисуете действительно в `OnPaint`, то всё должно быть нормально. Предположу, что вы рисуете на графиксе, созданном вручную вызовом `CreateGraphics()`. Вместо него используйте графикс из аргумента `PaintEventArgs`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да все рисуется в переопределенном методе OnPaint, НО! это все в UserControl

Comment: Совершенно не важно, какой это контрол. Важен графикс.

Comment: Кстати, укажите метку WinForms. Это же оно?

Answer (score 2):

Рисовать надо на `e.Graphics` в обработчике события `Paint`.